# Installing python3.6 idle

Tags: command-line, software-installation, python3, idle-python

I am trying to install python 3.6 idle. I have used `sudo apt-get install python3.6` but keep getting the same error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3.6'
```

Please help

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a recent LTS Ubuntu version (14.04 & 16.04) you can add the deadsnake PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y && sudo apt-get update
```

They state you can use other versions as well with this PPA however its not supported/tested.